# Batch Clone Build Definitions TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

Is there a way in TFS to clone multiple build definitions pointed at a new branch? Say I have 6 build definitions pointed at the trunk, and then add a branch that needs all 6. Today, I have to clone one at a time, and it is very inconvenient.

I have looked at Community TFS Build Extensions, but am not sure if functionality exists in there, and if it is, how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tfpt to do the automated cloning part.

Examples:

Clone the HelloWorld_Main definition as HelloWorld_Release
tfpt builddefinition /clone Contoso\HelloWorld_Main Contoso\HelloWorld_Release

Clone the HelloWorld_* definitions from the Contoso to Contoso2 team project
tfpt builddefinition /clone Contoso\HelloWorld_* Contoso2

I know you can use the TFS API to programmatically change cloned build definitions to change paths and configuration values inside of them.  Although, because of the level of customization of build definitions, this is not necessarily straight-forward.  For example, you may have branch-specific configuration data that is more than just the name of the branch.

To edit process parameters programmatically see something like this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a032086-dcf3-4585-abdf-bfb12f42bf5c/how-to-modify-the-tfs-build-definition-processparameters-programmatically?forum=tfsbuild